# Checking if a string begins with a given string

Tags: c#, string

I am new to programming.
I need to determine if a given string begins with something. For example to check if the string begins with "hi" to return true, but to return false if it's "high".

```
StartHi("hi there") -> true;
StartHi("hi") -> true;
StartHi("high five") -> false.
```

I've tried with .Substring and .StartsWith, but i can't figure out how to make them return false "high five".
I've tried the like this:

```
public static bool StartHi(string str)
{
    bool firstHi;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The string is empty!");
    }
    else if(str.Substring(0,2) == "hi")
    {
        firstHi = true;
        Console.WriteLine("The string starts with \"hi\"");
    }
    else
    {
        firstHi = false;
        Console.WriteLine("The string doesn't start with \"hi\"");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

    return firstHi;
```

}
With .StartsWith, just changed the "else if":

```
else if(str.StartsWith("hi"))
{
    firstHi = true;
    Console.WriteLine("The string starts with \"hi\"");
}
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Split on whitespace then check first entry equal to hi

Comment: use regex `@"^hi\b"`

Comment: hi and high clearly begin with the same first two characters, therefore .Substring(0,2) and .StartsWith("hi") would always return true

Comment: Claiming that "high five" doesn't start with "hi" seems odd to me. Claiming that it doesn't start with "hi" *as a word* would make more sense...

Comment: Does Hi, pass your req

Comment: Surely you could just check for `str.StartsWith("hi ")` ?

Comment: @HarrySweetman but that would fail if "str" was just "hi".

Comment: @Sk93 ah of course, it depends what OP needs the check for I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `StartHi` method like below using `Split`

```
    public static bool StartHi(string str)
    {
        bool firstHi = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The string is empty!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return false;
        }

        var array = str.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (array[0].ToLower() == "hi")
        {
            firstHi = true;
            Console.WriteLine("The string starts with \"hi\"");
        }
        else
        {
            firstHi = false;
            Console.WriteLine("The string doesn't start with \"hi\"");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        return firstHi;
    }
```

Note: 
*If you have other strings like "hi!" or "Hi? Don't say hi to me", then you can extend the `Split` to something like below.*

```
var array = str.Split(new string[] {" ", "!", "?"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (array[0].ToLower() == "hi") //convert to lower and check
```

*Regex is probably your best bet if it gets more complicated and look towards it. I can't give it one since I'm not great with it.*

Comment: this will throw an error if the string is null. It also doesn't accomodate for upper/lower case, and it won't work for "hi!" or similar punctuation.

Comment: @Sk93 -  this won't throw an error when string is null and this is as per OP's possible strings in the question. Although point noted, I will update my answer

Comment: @Sk93 - I see what you're saying about it being null.. it needed a return in the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways come to mind to achieve this.
The first would be to split the string on whitespace, into an array, then check the first entry of the array for "hi":

```
string[] words = str.split(' ');
if ((words.length == 0 && str == "hi") || (words[0] == "hi"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

The second would be to utilise the Regex and check if it matches "hi" at the start of the string:

```
return (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, @"^hi\b").Success);
```

Both of these will only find "hi" however (case specific).
If you wish to check for "hi", "Hi", "HI" or "Hi", then you would likely want to use the ".ToLower()" method on the string object:

```
string lowerStr = str.ToLower();
string[] words = lowerStr.split(' ');
if ((words.length == 0 && lowerStr == "hi") || (words[0] == "hi"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

An example of your StartHi method may look like this:

```
public static bool StartHi(string str)
{
    bool firstHi;    
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The string is empty!");
    }
    else
    {
        string strLower = str.ToLower();
        string[] words = strLower.split(' ');
        if ((words.length == 0 && strLower == "hi") || (words[0] == "hi"))
        {
            firstHi = true;
            Console.WriteLine("The string starts with \"hi\"");
        }
        else
        {
            firstHi = false;
            Console.WriteLine("The string doesn't start with \"hi\"");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    return firstHi;
}
```

If you needed to expand your criteria, and treat examples like "Hi!" and "Hi?" as a success, you should lean towards the Regex method. 
In which case, your method may look like the following:

```
public static bool StartHi(string str)
{
    bool firstHi;    
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The string is empty!");
    }
    else if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, @"^hi\b").Success))
    {        
        firstHi = true;
        Console.WriteLine("The string starts with \"hi\"");
    }
    else
    {
        firstHi = false;
        Console.WriteLine("The string doesn't start with \"hi\"");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    return firstHi;
}
```

Comment: What about `Hi!`? Or `Hi, anybody there?`. In this cases, spliting on whitespace does not work (the regex solution would).

Comment: For the regex solution, you could also use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` (if that's what OP wants, I dunno).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to return true if your string starts with the WORD high. This means that you want a non-word character after the h and the i. Non-word characters are called white-spaces (tabs, commas, semicolons, line feeds and a lot other ones.

You can use StartsWith to find if it starts with "hi".
To check if the the character after the hi is a whitespace use the static function String.IsNullOrWiteSpace(character after hi)
To get to the character after hi: use String.Remove.

Other problems that you'll have to face: What to do with upper case and lower case: do you define the following as true?

- HI
- hI